# Get Number Lines Currently in .net Maui Editor element

Tags: maui

I am trying to get the current number of lines in an editor element. The cursor position just tells me how many characters into the text the cursor is position.

I have set a breakpoint on a tap gesture and cannot find any relevant info.

Comment: How do you measure number of lines?  You could have a single long string that wraps onto multiple lines of display - is that one line or many?

Comment: In my case many. Do not count cr/lf as a line.

Comment: you probably need to look at the native platform controls and see if they provide a way to determine this.  If they do then create a handler to expose that to MAUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get Number Lines Currently in .net Maui Editor element

You can use the following code to achieve it:

```xml
int a = ed.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;

<ScrollView>
    <Editor x:Name="ed"/>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

I enter two lines and then click the button. It can get the number lines that I enter currently.